# How to stop React from showing typescript errors?

Tags: react-typescript

I am using react+typescript via react cra.
I used older react 16 initially and lately upgraded everything to the last version.

My package.json looks like

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.0",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.4.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "eslint": "^8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "storybook": "^7.4.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

eslintrc.json

```
module.exports = {
    extends: [
        'react-app',
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:import/errors',
        'plugin:import/warnings',
        'plugin:import/typescript',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
        'plugin:storybook/recommended',
    ],
    rules: {
        'import/order': [
            'error',
            {
                groups: ['builtin', 'external', 'internal', ['parent', 'sibling']],
                pathGroups: [
                    {
                        pattern: 'react',
                        group: 'external',
                        position: 'before',
                    },
                    {
                        pattern: '@/**',
                        group: 'external',
                        position: 'after',
                    },
                ],
                pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ['react'],
                'newlines-between': 'always',
                alphabetize: {
                    order: 'asc',
                    caseInsensitive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
        'sort-imports': [
            'error',
            {
                ignoreDeclarationSort: true,
            },
        ],
        // Include .prettierrc.js rules
        'prettier/prettier': ['error', {}, { usePrettierrc: true }],

        'react/display-name': 'warn',
        'import/no-anonymous-default-export': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
    },
};
```

Doing `eslint` command or in IntelliJ I see no error, but when doing `yarn start` I see the following image:
[image]

What I also don't understand is why these errors don't show in the editor but only during react start.

I can fix this easily by doing a change like `P extends React.JSX.IntrinsicAttributes` or tsignore but don't get it why it happens.

PS: This and many other errors happened after migrating to the latest react version. I fixed lots of them especially due to missing `children` in React.FC newer version but some errors are still lurking in ts still.